# I need help on what to do next in trying to create a listview for android

Tags: java, android

So i'm fairly a beginner at this but what i want to do is create a listview with two pictures and three text views. I created a class called custom list to serve as my adapter the problem i am running into is in my main activity listed here I can't set that adapter to the actually listview what did i do wrong. The error i get when i try to add the listView to oncreate is that i'd need a local variable.

class MainActivity

```
package j.motors.cars;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

// i have alot going on here can't figure out which way i want to use this array adapter 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<Craigslist> myCraigs = new ArrayList<Craigslist>();
    String[] make = {
            "Chevy",
            "Ford",
            "Dodge",
            "Hyundai",
            "Jeep",
            "Toyata",
            "Honda",
            "Kia"
    };
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    };
    String[] price = {
            "$1500",
            "$3000",
            "$1700",
            "$800"
    };
    Integer[] arrow = {
            R.drawable.imgright,
            R.drawable.imgright,
            R.drawable.imgright,
            R.drawable.imgright,
    };
    String[] description = {
            "This car runs well and has all the right parts",
            "This car is a steal at the price since it barely has 15 miles on it",
            "Almost new condition",
            "This car runs well"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateCraigslist();
        CustomList adapter = new
                CustomList(MainActivity.this, make, imageId, price, description, arrow);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setadapter(adapter)


    }

    private void populateCraigslist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String make, int imageID, String description, String price, int arrow
        myCraigs.add(new Craigslist("Good", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Great condition", "$1500", R.drawable.imgright));
        myCraigs.add(new Craigslist("Great", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Has a few hundred miles on it but it runs in good condition", "3000", R.drawable.imgright));
        myCraigs.add(new Craigslist("Alright", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Steal even at this price", "2000", R.drawable.imgright));
        myCraigs.add(new Craigslist("Excellent", R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Has a few hundred miles on it", "800", R.drawable.imgright));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

class CustomList

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] make;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    private final String[] description;
    private final String[] price;
    private final Integer[] arrow;

    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[ ] make, 
                      Integer[] imageId, 
                      String[] description, 
                      String[] price, 
                      Integer[] arrow) {

        super(context, R.layout.row, make);

        this.context = context;
        this.make = make;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.arrow = arrow;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
        TextView txtDesc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);
        TextView txtMake = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.makeTV);
        TextView txtPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.carIV);
        ImageView ivArrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.arrowIV);
        txtMake.setText(make[position]);
        txtPrice.setText(price[position]);
        txtDesc.setText(description[position]);
        iv.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        ivArrow.setImageResource(arrow[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: but where is your `ListView` and where you set adapter to your `ListView`?

Comment: Add Code CustomList (Base Adapter class) so i have to exact idea which side prblm adapter or main class

Comment: just added it to the original

Comment: and simple plan that's the problem everytime i try to add the listView I see an error saying it has to be a local variable but I call it in oncreate like normal

Comment: but Create `ListView` reference Globally and try

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ follow this link it have a sample project of custom list view

Comment: Thank you Nain that's to advanced for me in that he's getting the data off the internet while i already have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this for bind listview

```
package j.motors.cars;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
   String[] make = {
        "Chevy",
          "Ford",
          "Dodge",
          "Hyundai",
          "Jeep",
          "Toyata",
          "Honda",
          "Kia"
      } ;
      Integer[] imageId = {
          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
          R.drawable.ic_launcher,
      };
      String[ ] price = {
              "$1500",
              "$3000",
              "$1700",
              "$800"
      };
      Integer[] arrow = {
              R.drawable.imgright,
              R.drawable.imgright,
              R.drawable.imgright,
              R.drawable.imgright,
          };
      String[ ] description = {
              "This car runs well and has all the right parts",
              "This car is a steal at the price since it barely has 15 miles on it",
              "Almost new condition",
              "This car runs well"
      };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter();
    lv.setadapter(adapter)


}


public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return make.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        holder.imageview2 = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
                    holder.tex1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                    holder.tex2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
                    holder.tex3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
     holder.imageview1.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
         holder.imageview2.setImageResource(arrow[position]);
     holder.txt1.setText(make[position]);
         holder.txt2.setText(price[position]);
         holder.txt3.setText(description[position]);


    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt1,txt2,txt3;
    ImageView imageView1,imageview2;


}

}
}
```

this is a simple way to integrate listview in android.

Comment: Now this I can do thank you thank you thank you Mital

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have an `ArrayAdapter` where String is the parameterized type (between the angle brackets), but your list items aren't really Strings. At the very least, you should encapsulate the attributes of each list item into an object of some kind, then have a list/array of that object instead of multiple lists/arrays of different kinds.

I really think making your own adapter (extending from `BaseAdapter`) is better than extending the framework adapter. Regardless, you should watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=9KxpU87zLs68oQTDmoGwAQ&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=ch1Dqf9uc2qPoizkmQqs6Q) to understand how adapters work and how to write one properly.

Comment: thank you for your help I kind of understand what you are saying but i have no clue on how to implement it. I'm guessing your saying to make my data private while using getters and setters right. Anyway I'll watch the video see a little better what you are saying

Comment: No, I'm saying you have 5 disparate arrays of different types and taking the Nth item from each array to compose the actual Nth item of your list. They have no relation to each other at all. You should have one list of N items, where each item has the attributes that represent it. What do you think is easier to maintain? This will also help you when making your adapter; even if you still extend `ArrayAdapter`, you use your special type instead of String between the angle brackets. You should be able to implement getItem() of the adapter and return an object representing the entire list item.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
`lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);`
```

code in onCreate()
to

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Delclare

```
ListView lv;
```

above

```
private List<Craigslist> myCraigs = new ArrayList<Craigslist>();
```

and change CustomList as Follows

```
    class CustomList extends BaseAdapter 
{
     private final Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
     private final String[] make;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    private final String[] description;
    private final String[] price;
    private final Integer[] arrow;

   class ViewHolder 
   {
     TextView tvMake,tvPrice,tvDesc;
     ImageView ivArrow,iv;
   }

    public CustomList(Activity activity,String[ ] make, Integer[] imageId,
                 String[] description, String[] price, Integer[] arrow) 
    {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        context=activity;

        this.context = context;
        this.make = make;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.arrow = arrow;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        int count=make.length;// Set the total list item count
        return count ;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


           @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {

         ViewHolde holder=null;
         if(converView==null)
        {
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
            holder.ivArrow = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
            holder.tvMake = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            holder.tvDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        }
        else
        {
           holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }



        holder.tvMake.setText(make[position]);
        holder.tvPrice.setText(price[position]);
        holder.tvDesc.setText(description[position]);
        holder.iv.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.ivArrow.setImageResource(arrow[position]);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        return convertView;
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you user I really appreciate you breaking it down sometimes it's just hard to know where to put what while looking at the code